# Content Porter import NullReferenceException importing schema's

Tags: 2013-sp1, content-porter-2013

Wondering if you can help me with an issue here. Can somebody tell me what I can do about this error?

The Content Porter seems to fail on me. It crashes and then nothing...

[image]

[image]

**Update**
I've pinpointed it to two schemas. If I export and import those, it doesn't work using the Import / Export service of Tridion 2013 sp1, but they do import using the old format!

It seems it is a bug in the Import / Export service in Tridion sp1?

Comment: Maybe your CP package (.zip) is (b)locked?

Comment: It is actually importing as you can see in the first screenshot. The empty master with the default templates is importing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will file a bug report to SDL Customer Support. Clearly this is an issue, but I hoped for a quick fix. In the meantime I found a workaround.

Should somebody have any trouble with the Import / Export Service in Tridion 2013 sp1 (or higher), please use the legacy export (2013 or older option). That way, the import might still work. Which it did in my case...

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi @Thijs. Did you get a resolution to this from Support?

Answer (score 1):

This issue may have already been hot-fixed by CM_2013.1.0.87921 - Described as:

> During partial import, to resolve circular dependencies, the
>   dependencies on an XML content are stripped to allow the import.
>
> In some cases the order was incorrect leading to a situation when we
>   try to access data already stripped out.

This is available on [the Tridion 2013 SP1 Hotfixes page](https://www.sdltridionworld.com/downloads/hotfixes/sdl_tridion_2013_sp1/index.aspx) SDL Tridion World.

Answer (score 0):

Given the "suboptimal" error handling (such a NullReferenceException should never happen and doesn't help to pinpoint the root cause), I would recommend to contact SDL Customer Support for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've exact the same issue... and I've created a ticket about this by Tridion Support about 2 weeks ago. Still hoping for a fix on short notice. 
Thijs, I will check your work around. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned I had the same issue. In my case this issue is caused because of the following import setting: 
"Run import process in transaction" 
When I deselect this option, the import seems to run flawless.

Hope this helps.